# boundry condition with javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

suppose if i have a string in javascript

var str=if {{SQL}}.Employee.name else {{SQL}}.EmployeeContact.phone

and want to replace {{SQL}}.Employee with {{SQL}}.Employee1

desired output is:

if {{SQL}}.Employee1.name else {{SQL}}.EmployeeContact.phone

but i am getting the output as below:

if {{SQL}}.Employee1.name else {{SQL}}.Employee1Contact.phone

below is the code for the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>
      <p id="demo">if {{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE.name else {{SQL}}.EMPLOYEECONTACT.phone</p>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
             var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
             var tr="{{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE"
             var res = str.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+tr+"\\b","g"),"
                   {{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE1");
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use regexp "{{SQL}}\.Employee(?!\w)"

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're describing isn't the same as in your example code. The described problem is a missing *word boundary*. That is present in your code.

The problem in the code is that you have a *word boundary* **before** the expression as well. That's supposed to match the position between the space and the first `{`, and that doesn't qualify as a word boundary.

```
if {{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE
  ^^ - between these there's no word boundary since neither
       space, nor the opening bracket are word characters.
```

Here's a **working** code sample with the first *word boundary* removed:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <p>Click the button to replace "blue" with "red" in the paragraph below:</p>
          <p id="demo">if {{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE.name else {{SQL}}.EMPLOYEECONTACT.phone</p>
          <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
          <script>
             function myFunction() {
                 var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
                 var tr="{{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE";
                 var re = new RegExp( tr + "\\b","g");
                 var res = str.replace(re,"{{SQL}}.EMPLOYEE1");
                 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
             }
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

I've also escaped the period in the regex, since the unescaped `.` in the regex matches any character.